# grub-install error when running trying to install gnupg on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I am trying upgrade mongodb on my Ubuntu 18:04 system and I am getting the following error when I execute the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg
```

This is the error:

```
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.187.2~18.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.167~) | grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.167~); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has less than week of support left. There's no point in troubleshooting unless you want to release upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have two packages in an incompletely installed state: `grub-efi-amd64-signed` and `shim-signed`. This message suggests the possible reason why those packages have failed to completely install:

```
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

Apparently your EFI System Partition is not mounted at `/boot/efi`, or there is something wrong with it.

You should fix this before trying to install any new software (like `gnupg`).

Those updates might be related to Ubuntu's old Secure Boot certificate getting blacklisted (because of BootHole-related security vulnerabilities), so if you have Secure Boot enabled and `fwupd` has already delivered the lates Secure Boot blacklist (`dbx`) update, your system might not be able to boot without disabling Secure Boot or other manual actions until the updated `shim-signed` and `grub-efi-amd64-signed` are fully installed.